# fill up empty values with same value of another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas dataframe like the following:

[image]

How do I fill up the empty cells with same policy numbers for same product type as they exist?

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Sorry for the confusion, I am adding my sample dataframe now:

> > sample=[{'POLICY NUMBER':' ','PRODUCT TYPE':'MED'},{'POLICY NUMBER':' ','PRODUCT TYPE':'MED'},{'POLICY NUMBER':'433M49763','PRODUCT TYPE':'MED'},{'POLICY NUMBER':'433M86968','PRODUCT TYPE':'MED'},{'POLICY NUMBER':' ','PRODUCT TYPE':'TED'},{'POLICY NUMBER':'566D158635 ','PRODUCT TYPE':'TED'},{'POLICY NUMBER':'655D158635','PRODUCT TYPE':'TED'},{'POLICY NUMBER':'789D158635','PRODUCT TYPE':'TED'}]
> >
> > pd.DataFrame(sample)

please note that the empty cells have " " in them too, they are not NaN across the whole dataframe

Adding to the question above. If I have the altered dataframe as above. How do i get to the following dataframe:

[image]

Comment: I think not, need also `groupby`

Comment: `df.groupby('Prod type')['Policy Number'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Comment: @COLDSPEED, not exact dupe, this one is groupby and fillna though i sure there would be a dupe for that as well

Comment: Or maybe `df.groupby('Prod type')['Policy Number'].transform(lambda x: x.dropna().iat[0])`

Comment: @Vaishali - not, because second `ffill` working with Series returned from `df.groupby('Prod type')['Policy Number'].bfill()`

Comment: Got it, I wasnt too sure and couldnt test is because there is no sample df. Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Still no match dupe...

Comment: @jezrael I cannot see the images in the posts (imgur is blocked here) so I just added it based on your comment. Feel free to reopen if those do not answer the question.

Comment: @ayhan - try find dupe by my comment, need groupby  ffill  bfill together...

Comment: @ayhan - try find dupe, but not successfull

Comment: @jezrael I reopened it, feel free to answer it

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

If only one same category per group and no data are empty `string`s :

```
df['POLICY NUMBER'] = (df.groupby('PRODUCT TYPE')['POLICY NUMBER']
                         .transform(lambda x: x[x != ''].iat[0]))

print (df)
  POLICY NUMBER PRODUCT TYPE
0     433M86968          MED
1     433M86968          MED
2     433M86968          MED
3     433M86968          MED
4    566D158635          TED
5    566D158635          TED
6    566D158635          TED
7    566D158635          TED
```

Or if posible there are not always empty stings, but sometimes there are `wtrailing whitespaces`, need [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['POLICY NUMBER'] = (df['POLICY NUMBER'].str.strip().groupby(df['PRODUCT TYPE'])
                                  .transform(lambda x: x[x != ''].iat[0]))

print (df)
  POLICY NUMBER PRODUCT TYPE
0     433M86968          MED
1     433M86968          MED
2     433M86968          MED
3     433M86968          MED
4    566D158635          TED
5    566D158635          TED
6    566D158635          TED
7    566D158635          TED
```

Solution with sorting and transform `last` value:

```
df['POLICY NUMBER'] = (df.sort_values(['PRODUCT TYPE','POLICY NUMBER'])
                         .groupby('PRODUCT TYPE')['POLICY NUMBER']
                         .transform('last'))
print (df)
  POLICY NUMBER PRODUCT TYPE
0     433M86968          MED
1     433M86968          MED
2     433M86968          MED
3     433M86968          MED
4    566D158635          TED
5    566D158635          TED
6    566D158635          TED
7    566D158635          TED
```

EDIT: You need replace empty strings by `NaN`s and then use `bfill` for back forward filling `NaN`s with `ffill` for forward fillin NaNs:

```
df['POLICY NUMBER'] = (df['POLICY NUMBER'].str.strip()
                                          .replace('',np.nan)
                                          .groupby(df['PRODUCT TYPE'])
                                          .transform(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill()))

print (df)
  POLICY NUMBER PRODUCT TYPE
0     433M49763          MED
1     433M49763          MED
2     433M49763          MED
3     433M86968          MED
4    566D158635          TED
5    566D158635          TED
6    566D158635          TED
7    789D158635          TED
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @jezrael. It is a big help :)

Comment: @jezrael.......i hope you can help me with a slightly modified version of the same problem